Clang-Tidy and boost::asio::awaitable<void>
I am trying to use clang-tidy with a Windows & Linux targets. This is for a large project built using CMake.
The C++20 code compiles and works correctly for both targets. It also passes through clang-tidy without error on Linux (WSL & Ubuntu).
The bigger problem is with the following function prototype:
boost::asio::awaitable<void> CoCreateClientConnection(
    std::string _peerName,
    std::string _networkAddress,
    uint16_t _port);

clang-tidy reports:
ClientConnector.hpp:46:18: error: no template named 'awaitable' in namespace 
boost::asio' [clang-diagnostic-error]
    boost::asio::awaitable<void> CoCreateClientConnection(
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

I am using:
Boost 1.84
clang-tidy 17.0.1
cl.exe 19.37.32824  (from Visual Studio 2022)
My CMakeLists.txt contains:
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy
"-extra-arg=-Wno-unknown-warning-option"
"-checks=-.cppcoreguidelines-"
"-extra-arg=/EHsc"
"-header-filter=/^(?!._deps).$/")
I have also tried using a config-file which contains:
Checks: '-*,boost-*,cppcoreguidelines-*,modernize-*'
CheckOptions:
  - key: 'boost-*'
    value: 'boost::asio::awaitable'
ExtraArgs:
  - '-Wno-unknown-warning-option'
  - '/EHsc'
HeaderFilterRegex: '/^(?!.*_deps).*$/'

How do I either:

Tell clang that the template boost::asio::awaitable<void> is valid
Skip linting for boost::asio::awaitable<void>
Ignore any errors related to boost::asio

Note for normal Windows builds CMake uses MSBuild but for CppCheck and clang-tidy I have to use Ninja as the CMake Generator or the CppCheck and clang-tidy commands are not executed.
From the header file boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp it looks like the template is conditionally included if BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT is defined.
The code in boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp is:
#  if defined(BOOST_ASIO_MSVC)
#   if (_MSC_VER >= 1928) && (_MSVC_LANG >= 201705) && !defined(__clang__)
#    define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT 1
#   elif (_MSC_FULL_VER >= 190023506)
#    if defined(_RESUMABLE_FUNCTIONS_SUPPORTED)
#     define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT 1
#    endif // defined(_RESUMABLE_FUNCTIONS_SUPPORTED)
#   endif // (_MSC_FULL_VER >= 190023506)

so the issue appears to be with:
My current workaround is to force the definition when/if clang-tidy is configured in CMake, i.e.
set(CLANG_TIDY_CONFIG_FILE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.clang-tidy-config")
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${CLANG_TIDY_CONFIG_FILE}" CLANG_TIDY_CONFIG_CMAKE)

add_definitions(-DBOOST_ASIO_HAS_CO_AWAIT)

set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY clang-tidy "--config-file=${CLANG_TIDY_CONFIG_CMAKE}")


I concur with your analysis. This is how I've "fixed" it for my dev setups too. Some time in the past an upgrade to clang libs removed the need to pass those flags, so I removed them from my CMake files. However, sometimes I still had YouCompleteMe warn me of missing things surrounding c++20 coroutines. Oh well, things are already lightyears better than back in the day stuck in VS96...
